# How to check if item already exists in object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to check if an `item.name` already exists in the object array so it will not push that existing object to the array.

This is the piece of code:

```
loadedVariations.forEach(function(item){
      console.log('item', item.name.indexOf(name));

      if(name === tests[test].id && item.name.indexOf(name) < 0){
          console.log(item.name)

          loadedVariations.push({name: name, variation: variation});
          tests[test].callback(name, variation);    
          console.log('tests', tests[test], variation, loadedVariations);

          if(variation === '1'){
            value = "control"
          } else {
            value = "variationb"
          }

          localStorage.setItem('gtmTest', JSON.stringify(loadedVariations));
        }
    })
```

This is the output in my localstorage:

```
gtmTest: 

[{"name":"globalPassFrame_review","variation":"1"},
{"name":"globalPassFrame_review","variation":"1"},
{"name":"socialshare_bar","variation":"2"},
{"name":"socialshare_bar","variation":"2"}]
```

This is an AB Test in google tag manager with an helping script which runs on multiple test scripts so it runs multiple times that's why I need to check if item already exists in the object array so it doesn't push the same object twice.

Comment: Please provide a snippet with some sample data and your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how do you can iterate over your `json object` by using [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and match name  . If you want to have array of unique Names you can iterate using forEach and check if it is not present in array .

```js
var object = [{"name":"globalPassFrame_review","variation":"1"},{"name":"globalPassFrame_review","variation":"1"},{"name":"socialshare_bar","variation":"2"},{"name":"socialshare_bar","variation":"2"}];

var tobeFound='globalPassFrame_review';

object.every(function (elem, i) {
    if(elem.name == tobeFound ){
     console.log('element found at index '+i);
      return false ;
   }
});

// In case you want to store uniue Names
var uniqueNames=[];
object.forEach(function (elem, i) {
     if(!uniqueNames.includes(elem.name)){
        uniqueNames.push(elem.name);
    }
});
console.log(`unique Names are ${uniqueNames}`);

// Using ES6 style of code.
const uniqueNamesArr = [...new Set( object.map(obj => obj.name)) ];
console.log(uniqueNamesArr);
```

Comment: use simpler version of forEach loop.